# What is purpose of --s2k-* GnuPG options?

Tags: key-management, pgp

When I use `gpg --symmetric --s2k-` and press tab some options appear:

```
--s2k-cipher-algo
--s2k-count
--s2k-digest-algo
--s2k-mode
```

What do those options do?

Comment: http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.en.html *Find -> "--s2k"*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`--s2k-mode` sets [mode of operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1):

- 0: Simple (hash applied one time to password)
- 1: Salted (hash applied one time to password+8 byte salt)
- 3: Iterated and salted (hash applied chosen number of times to password+8 byte salt)

`--s2k-digest-algo` sets hash function used for password hashing

`--s2k-count` sets number of rounds this hash function will be applied

`--s2k-cipher-algo` chooses cipher for encrypting the plaintext using the hashed password

In GnuPG 1.4.12 defaults are (found experimentally):

```
--s2k-mode = 3
--s2k-digest-algo = SHA1 (supports MD5, RIPEMD-160, SHA2s too)
--s2k-count = 65536 (supports from 1024 to 65011712)
--s2k-cipher-algo = CAST5 (supports 3DES, CAST5, Blofish, AES, Twofish, Camellia too)
```

You can see how your existing keys are encrypted by typing `gpg --list-packets ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg`

**But** all algorithms supported by GnuPG can be [efficiently automated](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3255/1516) at GPUs. So I suggest to use side implementation of `bcrypt` or `scrypt` instead of `--s2k-*` options and then give its result as a passphrase to GnuPG with `--s2k-mode` set to 0.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but how i can use ' bcrypt or scrypt instead of --s2k-* ' by the way i only use 'gpg -c' to encrypt files IF u can give me the ultimate secure code to use to encrypt my files that would be cool ^_^

Comment: @rezx It seems (because of downvotes) that I was incorrect when I wrote that bcrypt should be used instead of --s2k-* options. --s2k-* are OK too

Comment: @rezx I've asked [a question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3255/1516) about bcrypt vs --s2k-* and bcrypt is really better.

Comment: Just a note to anyone reading this question, the `--s2k` options may not do what you think if you have GPG 2.x (see [this issue](https://bugs.gnupg.org/gnupg/issue1800) in the bugtracker).

Comment: The man page of GPG 2.2.32 states that the default of `--s2k-cipher-algo` is AES-128.